# React-Query update cache after mutation performed

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have become slightly lost with `react-query`.  Essentially, I have a `useQuery` to fetch a user from my database.  Their details are added to a form and they can update and submit.

The problem I have is that the update is done to a different database.  The main database will be batch updated at a later point.  As such, instead of refetching the initial data, I need to use `setQueryData` to update the cache version.

```
queryClient = useQueryClient()

const { mutate } = useMutation(postUser, {
    onSuccess: async (response) => {
        console.log(response)

        queryClient.cancelQueries('user');
        const previousUser = queryClient.getQueryData('user');
        console.log(previousUser)
        queryClient.setQueryData('user', {
            ...previousUser,
            data: [
              previousUser.data,
              { '@status': 'true' },
            ],
          })
        return () => queryClient.setQueryData('user', previousUser)
    }
})
```

At the moment I have something like the above.  So it calls postUser and gets a response.  The response looks something like so

```
data:
    data:
        user_uid: "12345"
        status: "true"
        message: "User added."
        status: 1
```

I then `getQueryData` in order to get the cache version of the data, which currently looks like this

```
data:
    @userUuid: "12345"
    @status: ""
message: "User found."
status: 1
```

So I need to update the cached version @status to now be true.  With what I have above, it seems to add a new line into the cache

```
data: Array(2)
    0: {@userUuid: "12345", @status: ""}
    1: {@status: "true"}
message: "User found."
status: 1
```

So how do I overwrite the existing one without adding a new row?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not really react-query specific. In your `setQueryData` code, you set `data` to an array with two entries:

```
data: [
  previousUser.data,
  { '@status': 'true' },
],
```

first entry = `previousUser.data`
second entry = `{ '@status': 'true' }`

overriding would be something like this:

```
queryClient.setQueryData('user', {
  ...previousUser,
  data: {
    ...previousUser.data,
    '@status': 'true',
  },
})
```

On another note, it seems like your mixing optimistic the `onMutate` callback with the `onSuccess` callback. If you want to do optimistic updates, you'd implement the `onMutate` function in a similar way like you've done it above:

- cancel outgoing queries
- set data
- return "rollback" function that can be called `onError`

This is basically the workflow found [here in the docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/optimistic-updates).

if you implement `onSuccess`, you're updating the cache *after* the mutation was successful, which is also a legit, albeit different, use-case. Here, you don't need to return anything, it would be more similar to the [updates from mutation responses](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/updates-from-mutation-responses) example.